# PHP QueryString 404 Object Not Found

Tags: php, curl, query-string, file-get-contents

I am an Android developer having very little knowledge of PHP. I am stuck with this problem of getting 404 Error Object Not Found when reading variables from query string. I added .htaccess file as a result the error does go away but the variables are not read. Although if I read a URL without a query string it works perfectly. I can not think of a reason it should not work. Here's what I have tried:

PHP file:

Name of file: file_getTest.php

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
$baseUrl='http://xyz.com?language=en';
$language = $_GET['language'];
$session = $_GET['sessionID'];
$placeOrigin=$_GET['place_origin'];
$typeOrigin=$_GET['type_origin']; 
$nameOrigin=$_GET['name_origin'];
$homePage =($baseUrl."&sessionID=".$session."&place_origin=".$placeOrigin."&type_origin=".$typeOrigin."&name_origin=".$nameOrigin);

//if "echo file_get_contents($baseUrl)" is executed it works fine

//echo file_get_contents($homePage); //I have tried file_get_contents but no use

echo file_get_contents_curl($homePage);
```

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* file_getTest.php
```

Without .htacess file & using **curl()** I get this error:

The requested URL /test/file_getTest.php&sessionID=**value read**&place_origin=**value read**&type_origin=**value read**&name_origin=**value read** was not found on this server.

With .htaccess file & using **curl()** I get the following error:

HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found

Without .htacess file & using **file_get_contents()** I get this error:

The requested URL /test/file_getTest.php&sessionID=**value read**&place_origin=**value read**&type_origin=**value read**&name_origin=**value read** was not found on this server.

With .htaccess file & using **file_get_contents()** I get the following error:

file_get_contents(http://xyz.com?language=en&sessionID=&place_origin=&type_origin=&name_origin=): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found in C:\wamp\www\file_getTest.php on line 20

I would greatly appreciate any help. I have been stuck on this issue for some time now & can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: That is the reason I am stuck. I can not seem to find a fault but thanks for your input.

Comment: Does the framed URL works independently in a web browser? You need to validate those `$_GET` params though.

Comment: Yeap the URL works just fine. There's nothing wrong with it including the parameters in query string

Comment: can you access say `google.com` from PHP? Check configurations then.

Comment: Yeap works just fine. I don't have problem in accessing static URLs I have problems when it comes to GETting parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved. This seems pretty weird but all I did was to swap double quotes "" in $homepage with single quotes in the rest of the variables. After that, I encoded all the query string parameters & it worked like a charm.

so final code looks like this:

```
$baseUrl="http://xyz.com?language=en";

$session = $_GET["sessionID"];
$placeOrigin=$_GET["place_origin"];
$typeOrigin=$_GET["type_origin"]; 
$nameOrigin=$_GET["name_origin"];

$placeDestination=$_GET["place_destination"];
$typeDestination=$_GET["type_destination"];
$nameDestination=$_GET["name_destination"];

$sessionE=urlencode($session);
$placeOriginE=urlencode($placeOrigin);
$typeOriginE=urlencode($typeOrigin);
$nameOriginE=urlencode($nameOrigin);

$placeDestinationE=urlencode($placeDestination);
$typeDestinationE=urlencode($typeDestination);
$nameDestinationE=urlencode($nameDestination);

$homepage=$baseUrl.'&sessionID='.$sessionE.'&place_origin='.$placeOriginE.'&type_origin='.$typeOriginE.'&name_origin='.$nameOriginE.'&place_destination='.$placeDestinationE.'&type_destination='.$typeDestinationE.'&name_destination='.$nameDestinationE;
```